# How can I execute a method in a module from the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

I have a module in a file called `my_mod.rb` declared like this:

```
module Reports
  module MyMod

    def mymethod
      ...
    end

  end
end
```

I just want to run `mymethod`. It's not a class method obviously, so I can't run it like:

```
Reports::MyMod.mymethod
```

and yet I was hoping there was some way to get the method evaluated by the parser without have to go through a bunch of module_eval and module_function stuff. It should be easier than that, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

To run it from the rails console you just have to include it:

```
> include Reports::MyMod
> mymethod
```

Comment: Winner! Your solution is better than mine; I learned something new.

Comment: Not working for me in Ruby 2.6.3.
`MyMod.mymethod` not working either

Comment: not working for me (irb(main):012:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.3.0"
irb(main):013:0> Rails.version
=> "5.1.2"
irb(main):014:0>)

Comment: include JSON;   parse;  # works somehow. UPDATE: figured it out: I was missing a require statement for my custom module

Comment: Not working for Rails 6.0.3.7

Answer (score 2):

```
class A
  include Reports::MyMod
end

A.new.mymethod
```

Comment: Not working for Rails 6.0.3.7